# Task from my JavaScript exam - find first double var from array by the loop and brake

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am first time on Stack - could You help?
my exam:
Find array's index which describe first place of var which have double or more.

```js
    var f = [100,2,94,1,8,94,7,1,94,23];

    //U see - 94 is double and tiple.

    var firstIndex;

    //my result is 8 (Answer is 2 of course).

    for (i=0; i < (f.length-1); i++) {
    firstIndex = i;
    for (j = (firstIndex + 1); j < f.length; j++) {
        if ( f[j] == f[firstIndex] ) {
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(firstIndex);
```

Comment: @NickA How will that make any substantive difference?

Comment: @NickA If all the code is wrapped by a function and the `console.log` is replaced with a `return` the `break` won't operate any differently than it does now?  If you meant that the second loop should be in a new function and that function should `return`, you should clarify.

Comment: This is text from exercise: **In the `` `for``` loop, find out which number is the first, assign it to the` `firstIndex`` variable, and list its index in the console.**

Comment: @NickA You misunderstand me. Your "hint" is ambiguous as to what you are suggesting should be wrapped by a function. If one takes your comment to mean wrap all the posted code in a function and then replace the `console.log` with a `return` statement, the code would not operate any differently than it does now. I am simply saying that you should be more concise with your suggestion.

Comment: @NickA Uh, ok. I'm not sure why you see this as a "feud" or have deleted your prior comments. I guess we disagree on what the purpose of Stack Overflow is and how comments and answers should help.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no, you're right, the comment was probably a bit too ambiguous considering the question and perhaps I was a bit too flippant, apologies

Comment: @ScottMarcus as for deleting the prior comments, I feel my answer below better states what my intentions were and there was no need to leave a record of what had been said as it is either stated in the below or not relevant to answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `break` statement is *only* jumping out of the inner loop and *not* the outer loop hence why it's not printing the expected result. To overcome the problem you can simply declare a boolean variable before the outer loop and set it to `false` then when you find a match you can set it to `true`. Next, immediately after the inner loop check if that boolean flag is `true` and if it's then `break` again to jump out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` statement only exists the inner loop, because of this `firstIndex` will always be the last value of `i` (`f.length - 2`):

```
for (i=0; i < (f.length-1); i++) {   // Loop A
    firstIndex = i;
    for (j = (firstIndex + 1); j < f.length; j++) {    // Loop B
        if ( f[j] == f[firstIndex] ) {
            break;   // Only exists Loop B
        }
    }
    //  The break continues here
}
```

It may be easier for you to wrap your loops in a function which takes the array to be checked:

```
function checkDoubles(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < f.length - 1; i++){
        /*
        *   Omitted for you to solve
        */
    }
}

firstIndex = checkDoubles(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = [100,2,94,1,8,94,7,1,94,23];

//U see - 94 is double and tiple.
var foundDouble = false;
var firstIndex;

//my result is 8 (Answer is 2 of course).

for (i=0; i < (f.length-1) && !foundDouble; i++) {
firstIndex = i;
for (j = (firstIndex + 1); j < f.length; j++) {
    if ( f[j] == f[firstIndex] ) {
      foundDouble = true;
        break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(firstIndex);
```

That should work.
Simply use a boolean flag to quit the first `for`

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I would do it as follows... no need for double loops.

Although, I am not sure how efficient this is, but I trust that the built-in functions are optimized.

I used an intermediate variable for clarity, but it is optional.

References: JavaScript array built-in methods [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control) and [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf?v=control)

```js
var f = [100, 2, 94, 1, 8, 94, 7, 1, 94, 23];

// The value 94 at index=2 is the first duplicate.

var thisValue;

for (i = 0; i < (f.length - 1); i++) {
  thisValue = f[i];
  if (f.indexOf(thisValue) !== f.lastIndexOf(thisValue)) {
    console.log(i);
    break;
  }
}
```